# how scrollable text line inside a div without showing scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

plz see the below link :

[Long File Name Inside A Div](http://www.asanfile.com/Default.aspx?path=/Sony%20Ericsson/Flash%20File/Setool%20-%20Box/Flash%20Files%20All%20Language/C510/R1DA029)

when you see those long file names with firebug you will find a span that tell us ->

```
.FileName {
    float: left;
    width: 438px;
}
```

we have predefined width for this span!

q#1 : so why we have overflow in that div and how can i fix that ?

q#2(important) : is it possible to make that file name scrollable without showing scroll bars ?

**edit**
(with jquery or javascript or css)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a scrollbar, but do want to scroll, then the most apparent solution would be to use some javascript. If you're into jquery, here's some:

http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

I've tried one of them (http://www.demo.creamama.fr/plugin-scrollbar/), setting the div containing the text to `overflow: hidden;` and the div containing the scrollbar to `display: none;` to mimic your situation, and that gives me a scrollable div with no scrollbar.
However, I think from a UI point of view it's not the best idea to have a scrollable section without a scrollbar. At least something should light up (as with the Mac OS Lion scrollbars) indicating you can, or are, scrolling. You could style one of the javascript solutions out there to make this happen, for instance with a tiny scrollbar or indicator.

Comment: thanks for answer / would you plz show us a sample in jsfiddle!

Comment: I've tried to slap something together quickly in jsfiddle, but it doesn't go easily. If you could try to implement one of the jquery solutions, I'd be happy to take a look if it still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3):

You have an overflow because this text can't break (there are no spaces):

> R1DA029_APP_SW_1212_2395_GENERIC_KT_REDBROWNBLUE_CID52_49_DB3210

You could change the span's into div's and give them a height and an overflow:hidden.

Html:

```
<div class="FileName">R1DA029_APP_SW_1212_2395_GENERIC_KT_REDBROWNBLUE_CID52_49_DB3210  asangsm.com.rar</div>
```

Css:

```
.FileName{
    float: left;
    width: 438px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I don't think it's possible to make that file name scrollable without showing scrollbars.

Comment: thanks for answer / "I don't think it's possible to ..." but i think i saw something like that in a web site - so, there should be a way for doing that!

Comment: Maybe you could make something, when you mouseover the filename, the filename's text scrolls in the div?
Or when you mouseover a div become visible over the .FileName-div with the full length of the filename?

Comment: but what can i do about scroll bar! i just want to force that text scrollable without scoll bars and can scroll it with mouse only!

Comment: dear Mathieu i test your css / but we can 't have scroll bars in my links! will be very ugly!

Comment: also i test overfllow:hidden -> still have line break! why?

Comment: you have to set your height to 20px and change the span to a div. I will later take a look for the scrolling problem

Answer (score 1):

Short of using [CSS3's marquee](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/), I can see no simple solution. You would have to use Javascript.

As per avoiding the line break, you can use `white-space: nowrap;`.